# MeteorJS: Server side observeChanges perfomance issue

Tags: performance, meteor, aggregation

I'm implementing server side reactive aggregation and got some perfomance issues with observeChanges method.

```
Meteor.publish("ReactiveGroup", function (collectionName, filter, groupRules, options) {
    var self = this;
    var aggregate = function() {     
        var agregationPipe = _.clone(groupRules);
        agregationPipe.unshift({
            $match: filter
        });
        return collection.aggregate(agregationPipe);
    };

    var handle = collection.find(filter).observeChanges({
        _suppress_initial: true,
        changed: function(id, doc) {
            self.changed('ReactiveGroup', 0, aggregate());
        },
        removed: function (id, doc) {
            self.changed('ReactiveGroup', 0, aggregate());
        }
    });

    self.added('ReactiveGroup', 0, aggregate());
    self.ready();
});
```

In code above atmosphere extension mongodb-server-aggregation is used

Filtered collection returns about 200k of records and aggregation themselves works extremely fast - about 1sec, but observeChanges  execution took about 20s because it fire all added events regardless of added callback exist or not.

If there is any way to disable added events in observeChanges method?

Comment: I am not sure if it's even possible to prevent Meteor from fetching all these 200k records from the database. If I were you I would timestamp all changes on your documents and filter them with this timestamp to before defining the observer.